# Mi archivo js no me encuentra la ruta definida en laravel 5.8

Tags: php, html, laravel, ajax

Buenas tardes tengo un problema de rutas en laravel, tengo un archivo js en la carpeta public/js que envia datos mediante una url, y luego muestra un mensaje de alerta si funciono. Lo que haces es que al modificar un input text, se ejecuta este codigo.He probado mostrar un alert antes de que se ejecute el $.ajax y si funciona, pero luego de ahi no reconoce nada.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".cantidad").keyup(function(e){
    if($(this).val()!==''){
        if(e.keyCode==13){

            var id=$(this).attr('data-id');
            var precio=$(this).attr('data-precio');
            var cantidad=$(this).val();

            $(this).parentsUntil('.producto').find('.subtotal').text('Subtotal: '+(precio*cantidad));

            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: "{{ route('modificar_datos')}}",
                data:{
                    Id:id,
                    Precio:precio,
                    Cantidad:cantidad
                },
                success:function(e) {
                    alert("FUNCIONO");
                    $("#total").text('Total: '+e);
                } 
            });
        }
    }
});})$(document).on('ready',inicio);
```

Esta es mi ruta y ya probe ponerla en routes/web.php y routes/api.php como lei en algunas foros, he leido de todo y aun no me reconoce la ruta.

```
Route::get('modificar_datos','PagesController@modificar_datos')->name("modificar_datos");
```

Y esta es mi funcion, probe borrando todo el codigo y solo mostrando un mensaje con un echo 'Hola' y aun asi tampoco muestra, lo que me da que pensar que no me reconoce la ruta.

```
public function modificar_datos()
{   
    session_start();

                $arreglo=$_SESSION['carrito'];

                $total=0;
                $numero=0;
                for($i=0;$i<count($arreglo);$i++)
              {
               if($arreglo[$i]['Id']==$_POST['Id'])
            { 
               $numero=$i;
             }
                 }
                $arreglo[$numero]['Cantidad']=$_POST['Cantidad'];
                for($i=0;$i<count($arreglo);$i++){
                    $total=($arreglo[$i]['Precio']*$arreglo[$i]['Cantidad'])+$total;
                }
                $_SESSION['carrito']=$arreglo;

                echo $total;
}
```

Aqui se debe mostrar el total

```
  echo '<h2 id="total">Total: '.$total.'</h2>';
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me sale esto cuando entro a la consola de google chrome al trata de ejecutar el $ajax.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Creo que es por que no puedes usar `{{ route() }}` en un archivo js, esto es para plantillas blade, no estoy muy seguro pero hace tiempo tuve ese problema, prueba poniendo tu ruta completa a mano, yo lo solucione guardando el valor de la ruta en un `input - hidden` y con js recogia ese valor

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Agrega el Token en el data del Jquery

data: {
        "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
        "id": id
        }

Comment: pero el metodo se llama modificar_datos(), o desconozco algo?

Comment: Cambia el nombre de la funcion del controlador a modificarDatos

Comment: Esto no tiene nada que ver con el problema, la ruta se puede definir con _ o con - y va a funcionar igual. -1

Comment: Si acabo de probar y _ o - funciona igual no sera porque esta enviando un post necesta pasar {!! csrf_token() !!} en el jquery.

Comment: que raro ya puse el token, pero aun nada

Comment: si tiene google chrome entra con F12 a la consola y ve el error que te da al enviar y si puedes pasa lo que te sale en el error

Comment: ya entre a la consola amigo, acabo de actualizar el mensaje que me muestra al enviar.

Comment: Dale click a script.js:12 para ver en q parte del codigo te da el error te debe redirigir a dnd esta el error.

Comment: me muestra el error en la linea $.ajax {

Comment: mira por favor [answer]. Las respuestas tienen que ser claras y explicar bien el problema y la solución.

Comment: No entiendo porque fue marcado como respuesta correcta si no responde a la pregunta

Answer (score 3):

Ten en cuenta que al estar la ruta en un archivo js externo, el cuál está siendo leído directamente por el navegador, sin «pasar» por el framework Laravel (Blade en este caso), básicamente el navegador no interpreta la sintaxis de Blade.

La solución más práctica, sin necesidad de aplicar un montón de «ingeniería» innecesaria, es agregar la url directamente:

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "/modificar_datos",
```

Si deseas algo más sofisticado, puedes obtener las rutas de Laravel desde JS con [Laroute](https://github.com/aaronlord/laroute), o podrías buscar cómo obtenerlas en un json o similar.

Comment: el archivo js lo guardo en public/js,

Comment: Ok, mi respuesta no cambia en nada al saber eso.

Answer (score 2):

Desde el archivo blade los podrias hacer asi:

```
<script> url_ajax = '{{url("modificar_datos")}}' </script>
<script> csrf_token = '{{csrf_token()}}' </script>
<script src="{{ asset('vendor/js/modificar_datos.js') }}"></script>
```

Y dentro del modificar_datos.js llamas esas variables:

```
        $.ajax({
            url: url_ajax,
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                Precio:precio,
                _token: csrf_token
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (result) {
                console.log(result);
            }
        });
```