# Llamar rutas de laravel en jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, ajax

Tengo un script que si lo pongo en la página *HTML* funciona bien pero cuando lo paso a `mi main.js` no funciona inspeccionando la página me indica que no reconoce la ruta.

Ruta:

```
url: "{{ route('getmaquinas') }}",
```

Código de la función:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "{{ route('getmaquinas') }}",
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (response) {
        $.each(response.data, function (key, value) {
            plantSelect.append("<option value='" + value.id_maquina + "'>" + value.nombre_maquina + "</option>");
        });
```

Mi pregunta es esta es la forma correcta de llamar la ruta de *Laravel* a mi *JS*.

Comment: si señor  pero lo quiero pasar a una hoja js "no funciona" y llamarlo a mi pagina blade

Comment: No reconoce `{{ route('getmaquinas') }}` por eso es exclusivo de `blade`, por eso reescribirlo en un archivo que no sea `blade`, no lo reconocera, a menos que desde la pagina principal (que usa blade) le pases como variables todas las rutas que tienes

Comment: cual seria la sintaxis correcta para llamar la ruta desde js

Comment: De hecho no hay una manera para pasar eso a un archivo JS, porque esto se carga externamente y laravel solo puede pasar datos a una plantilla, en este caso blade

Comment: La solucion mas facil es simplemente pasar la ruta completa, o en el archivo principal (blade), definir las rutas y pasarlas por variables a otro archivo. Creo haber visto una pregunta parecida

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Mi archivo js no me encuentra la ruta definida en laravel 5.8](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/271578/mi-archivo-js-no-me-encuentra-la-ruta-definida-en-laravel-5-8)

Comment: Definitivo, de ese enlace toma lo que Shaz propone

Comment: no puedes usar sintaxis de blade en js, la unica es que llames la url absoluta apuntando a la raiz de proyecto, si quieres coloca la url y te ayudo en el codigo

Comment: @NicolasAldana Hola bro, podrias dar un ejemplo? si mi ruta es: https://prueba.com/users/create  como seria el codigo?