# url en ajax en laravel

Tags: laravel, ajax

estaba realizando un buscador dinamico usando laravel y ajax pero me da error cuando quiero pasar la url en ajax le adjunto el codigo

este es el codigo de la ruta de laravel

```
Route::post('/movie/buscar', 'PeliculaController@buscarPelicula')->name('buscar.pelicula');
```

este es el codigo de ajax

```
$('body').on('keyup', '#search-movie', function(){
    var buscadorDinamico = $(this).val();

   $.ajax({
       method: 'POST',
       url: "{{ route('buscar.pelicula') }}",
       dataType: 'json',
       data:{
         '_token': '{{ csrf_token() }}',
         buscadorDinamico: buscadorDinamico
       },
       success: function(res){

       }
   });
});
```

y esto es el error que me muestra en la consola
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y este es la url que me muestra el navegador
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Seguro el script esta en un archivo separado...tienes que colocar la ruta manualmente, ya que no puedes utilizar "blade" en un archivo que no sea ".blade". A menos que instales una libreria, pero ese es otro metodo

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Mi archivo js no me encuentra la ruta definida en laravel 5.8](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/271578/mi-archivo-js-no-me-encuentra-la-ruta-definida-en-laravel-5-8)

Comment: muchas gracias me funciono

Comment: Recuerda marcar como duplicado, ya que hay ese pregunta es similar a la tuya